# My visual studio 2019's symbol cache folder is empty

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, symbols

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I set the 'Symbol file (.pdb) locations, and set Cache symbols in this directory to 'E:\Symbols', but E:\Symbols is empty and every time I launch Visual Studio, it loads the symbols very slowly.

When I click 'Load all symbols' the folder is still empty.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

I set the symbol path to `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`.

After I add `_NT_SYMCACHE_PATH` symbol path, Visual Studio makes symbol files in my local folder.